# Python run Powershell as administrator

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script as administrator from python

As I cannot achieve this directly I tried running a batch file that run a PowerShell script

**python run bat file**

```
p = Popen([batFile, param1, param2, param3])
```

**bat file run powershell**

```
set param1=%1
set param2=%2
set param3=%3

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0test.ps1"" ""%param1%"" ""%param2%"" ""%param3%""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

**powershell code**

```
param
(
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2,
    [string]$param13
)

Write-Output $param1
Write-Output $param2
Write-Output $param3


Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```

My problem is that actually seems like the code is executed but the PowerShell is automatically closed 
after the write-output commands

Running the same files from windows cmd gives no issues, but when the code is executed from python the PowerShell terminal is automatically closed
How can I avoid this?

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate then I'd suggest searching for a pause command that works in powershell. In CMD the pause command is literally just "pause". Not sure about PowerShell though.